# Word for a decision made without any analysis?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for a decision that's already been made despite the relevant processes not having been followed / analysis done.

Foregone conclusion feels similar to what I'm after; but that implies that the facts are so obvious as to make the decision process moot; whilst I'm after a word for where the conclusion is based on one person's perspective without them having consulted relevant stakeholders / investigated the various options / collected evidence to support or dispute their arguments / etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'aiming more for something around the lack of inclusion of others' perspectives than the individual's haste of decision making' caveat put in the comment makes **unilateral decision** relevant:

> *unilateral* [adjective]
>
> 1. (of an action or decision): performed by or affecting only one person, group, or country involved in a situation, without the
>    agreement of another or the others.

[[Oxford Languages; courtesy of Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=unilateral+meaning&sca_esv=579769985&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&ei=zAFJZavzIJWM9u8P-vm5qAM&ved=0ahUKEwiric3906-CAxUVhv0HHfp8DjUQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=unilateral+meaning&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiEnVuaWxhdGVyYWwgbWVhbmluZzITEAAYigUYsQMYgwEYkQIYRhj5ATIFEAAYgAQyBRAAGIAEMgUQABiABDIFEAAYgAQyBRAAGIAEMgUQABiABDIFEAAYgAQyBRAAGIAEMgUQABiABDIqEAAYigUYsQMYgwEYkQIYRhj5ARiXBRiMBRjdBBhGGPQDGPUDGPYD2AEBSMc2UABYpzJwAHgBkAEAmAF8oAH-CqoBBDE2LjK4AQPIAQD4AQHCAggQABiKBRiRAsICBxAAGIoFGEPCAgsQABiABBixAxiDAcICCxAuGIAEGLEDGIMBwgIREC4YgAQYsQMYgwEYxwEY0QPCAgsQABiKBRixAxiRAsICDRAAGIoFGLEDGIMBGEPCAg4QABiKBRixAxiDARiRAsICKhAAGIoFGLEDGIMBGJECGEYY-QEYlwUYjAUY3QQYRhj0Axj1Axj2A9gBAeIDBBgAIEGIBgG6BgYIARABGBM&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)]  An example from the internet:

> - ... *he made a unilateral decision – without consulting the other director or shareholder – to shut down the corporation*.

[[Casetext; Callier v. Callier](https://casetext.com/case/callier-v-callier-1)]

Answer (score 3):

You might want *[snap decision](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/snap-decision)*, though that implies the absence not only of consultation and coordination with others, but also even of much reflection by the one person involved.

Comment: Thanks Paul; agreed that's close to what I'm after; but as you say, I'm aiming more for something around the lack of inclusion of others' perspectives than the individual's haste of decision making.